# How to send mail through servlets?

Tags: java, email, servlets

I am able to send mail through standalone application in java.but whenever i embedded the same code in the servlets ,i got exception that "could not connect to smtp.gmail.com  port 587 ". 
But the same code is working very fine when i am using standalone application , not servlets. I am using Mozilla firefox browser for servlets.

Comment: Post your code here...

Comment: I am using smtp.gmail.com and port 587. and its work in standalone application in java but not in servelets.

Comment: Post the code and we shall be able to help you more objectively.

Comment: Are your servlet container and your standalone app on the same machine/network?

Comment: yes... i am running both on same machine and network

Comment: Make a void method out of the code which is running in the stand-Alone application and then call it in the servlet it will definitely work if you do not miss out something. I have done that so Many times

Comment: Check My answer on what I am trying to explain. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Example Of what I am trying to say is like this:

Make Authenticator:

```
public class SMTPAuthenticator {

    public Session getSession() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
    }

    private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {

        private final PasswordAuthentication authentication;

        public Authenticator() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            authentication = new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
        }

        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return authentication;
        }
    }
}
```

Then a void Method in some other class:

```
public void sendemail() {

        SMTPAuthenticator sm = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        String username = "fromemailaddress@gmail.com";


        try {

            System.out.println("Sending ......");
            Message message = new MimeMessage(sm.getSession());
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("toemailaddress@host.com"));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(mess, "text/plain");
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(mess);
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            message.setContent(multipart);
            Transport.send(message);
    }
```

And Now finally in your Servlet Post method:

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    YourClass myclass = new YourClass();
    myclass.sendEmail();//Call the above send method.

    }
```